# Only 1 onComplete event triggered from multiple manual uploads with Fineuploader

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, fine-uploader

I have this multiple image fineuploader un my MVC 4 app. All works, my only problem is when I upload multiple images, I only get my "onComplete" event for the first image. Here is my HTML:

```
        <div id="fine-uploader">fine uploader</div>

            <div id="triggerUploadHolder" style="height: 28px;">
                <div id="triggerUpload" class="box" style="background-color: springgreen; width: 150px; display: none;">
                    <a href="#" onclick="triggerUpload(); return false;">Upload now</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <img id="attLoader" src="~/Content/FineUploader/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." style="display: none;" />

            <div id="thumbnail-fine-uploader"></div>

            @foreach (var attachment in Model.Attachments) {
                <div id="@attachment.Id"><a href="#" onclick="removeAttachment('@attachment.Id'); return false;">Remove this attachment</a><a href="@attachment.DocUrl" target="_blank"><img src="@attachment.DocUrl?w=250&mode=max" alt=""></a></div>
            }
```

And here is the javascript I run to initialize my uploader:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        createUploader();
    });

    function triggerUpload() {
        uploader.uploadStoredFiles();
    }

    var uploader;
    function createUploader() {
        uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: $('#fine-uploader')[0],
            autoUpload: false,
            debug: true,
            request: {
                endpoint: '/MyController/UploadAttachment',
                params: {
                    objLogId: $("#ObjLogModel_Id").val()
                }
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
                sizeLimit: 1024000,
                itemLimit: 5
            },
            messages: {

            },
            text: {
                uploadButton: "Click here or Drag a file from your computer",
                dragZone: "Drop File here to upload",
                cancelButton: "Cancel!"
            },
            template: '<div class="qq-uploader span12">' +
                '<div class="qq-upload-button btn btn-success" style="width: auto; color:red;">{uploadButtonText}</div>' +
                '<pre class="qq-upload-drop-area span12"><span>{dragZoneText}</span></pre>' +
                '<span class="qq-drop-processing"><span></span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
                '<ul class="qq-upload-list" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;"></ul>' +
                '</div>',
            callbacks: {
                onSubmit: function (id, name) {
                    $("#triggerUpload").fadeIn();
                    // console.log("onSubmit: " + id + " " + name);
                },
                onCancel: function (id, name) {
                    // console.log("onCancel: " + id + " " + name);
                    var submittedFileCount = uploader.getUploads({status: qq.status.SUBMITTED}).length;
                    if (submittedFileCount == 0) {
                        $("#triggerUpload").fadeOut();
                    }
                    // console.log("submittedFileCount: " + submittedFileCount);
                },
                onUpload: function (id, name) {
                    // console.log("onUpload: " + id + " " + name);
                    $("#triggerUpload").fadeOut();
                    $("#attLoader").fadeIn();
                },
                onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                    // console.log("onComplete - fileName: " + fileName + " // " + responseJSON);
                    // console.dir(responseJSON);
                    if (responseJSON.success) {

                        if ($("#ObjLogModel_Id").val() == "") {
                            $("#ObjLogModel_Id").val(responseJSON.objLogId);
                            history.pushState({ foo: "bar" }, "Saved", responseJSON.objLogId + "/");
                        }

                        $("#attLoader").fadeOut();

                        $('#thumbnail-fine-uploader').prepend('<div id="' + responseJSON.Id + '"><a href="#" onclick="removeAttachment("' + responseJSON.Id + '"); return false;">Remove this attachment</a><a href="' + responseJSON.url +'" target="_blank"><img src="' + responseJSON.url + '?w=250&mode=max" alt="' + fileName + '"></a></div>');

                        uploader.reset();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Should I be getting a seperate onComplete event for each upload or just one with a different response from the server?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you resetting the uploader in your onComplete callback?  That is surely the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been several days since I asked for clarification, so I'll just answer your question as best I can.

To directly answer your question: yes, you should receive a separate onComplete callback for each upload.  You are likely not receiving any callbacks after the first due to the fact that you are calling the `reset()` API method on the uploader in your onComplete callback.  Perhaps you do not understand what this method does.  Have a look at the documentation for clarification.  I suspect this is not what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Ray, (yeah it was the weekend), so I'm triggering the reset because I want my form to reinitialize so the user can be all good and ready to upload more. So I'll mark this as the answer because it is, but now I'd like to know how I can properly "reinitialize" the uploader. On the oncomplete event, I'm setting my thumbnail so I need them to trigger, is there a "multiple uploads completed event" ? Thanks!

Comment: Essentially I mostly need the "qq-upload-success" LI elements that indicate the successful uploads to not be added, I'll look for an option to do that in documentation.

Comment: Have a look at the getInProgress API function.